# Hangouts Interactive cards: how to add text fields?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Can we design an interactive card with a text filed?
I went through the documentation, i couldn't find any idea on how to create

1. checkbox
2. text field

can someone help me in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

### Considerations

At the moment there are no such widgets available. You can only interact with buttons or clicking on text paragraphs.

You should definitely [request this as a new feature](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/support#missing_features) if it's fundamental for your workflow.

### Proposed workaround

However, since this is a messaging App you can build a system that uses the very same "reply" feature in order to get back the user input and therefore simulate a text field.

### Respond to message events

You can play with the message events in order to parse the reply and use it in your application and provide an appropriate answer to your users.

### Build your prompts based on custom commands

You can also create custom commands to trigger different input requests if you want to.

### References

[Events](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events)

[Custom commands](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/slash-commands)